# Nested Animation end jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

### [Working, but with Inconsistent Page Changing](http://jsfiddle.net/Rz4dN/)

### [What I think correct approach, but the event is triggering](http://jsfiddle.net/Rz4dN/2/)

I'm experimenting with page transitions and using bind() to check for end of css event transition. After each class is added transition takes place and removed on completion, which is known by triggering of code in bind() call back, but only one bind call back works. So, the transition is incomplete.

### Jquery

```
$("a").click(function () {
    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = {
        direction: $('.mySelect').val()
    };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;
    var $sel = $('div.active');
    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'Contact') {
        $sel.addClass('active1');
        var $element = $('.active1').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            if (event.animationName === "three") {
                console.log('the event happened');
            }
            $sel.removeClass('active');
            $sel.removeClass('active1');
            $('#Container4').addClass('active');
            $('#Container4').addClass('active2');//.delay(1500).removeClass('active2');
        });
        var $element1 = $('.active2').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            alert("da1");
            $(this).removeClass('active2');
        });
    }

    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'About') {
        $sel.addClass('active1');
        var $element = $('.active1').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            if (event.animationName === "three") {
                console.log('the event happened');
            }
            $sel.removeClass('active');
            $sel.removeClass('active1');

            $('#Container3').addClass('active');
            $('#Container3').addClass('active2');//.delay(1500).removeClass('active2');
        });

        var $element1 = $('.active2').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('active2');
        });
    }

    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'Services') {
        $sel.addClass('active1');
        var $element = $('.active1').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            if (event.animationName === "three") {
                console.log('the event happened');
            }
            $sel.removeClass('active');
            $sel.removeClass('active1');
            $('#Container2').addClass('active');
        });

        $('#Container2').addClass('active');
        $('#Container2').addClass('active2');
        var $element1 = $('.active2').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('active2');
        });
    }

    if ($(this).attr('class') === 'Home') {
        $sel.addClass('active1');
        var $element = $('.active1').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            if (event.animationName === "three") {
                console.log('the event happened');
            }
            $sel.removeClass('active');
            $sel.removeClass('active1');
            $('#Container1').addClass('active');
        });

        $('#Container1').addClass('active');
        $('#Container1').addClass('active2');

        var $element1 = $('.active2').bind("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {
            $(this).removeClass('active2');
        });
        $('#Container1').toggle(effect, 'right', '10');
    }
});
```

Want Solution without use of third party plug and please explain why this inconsistency is happening in detail

### SOLUTION

### [Solved Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5rLDD)

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: Try using transit plugin.. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/ it has built in event handling for end of animation.

Comment: I am trying not to use plugin

Comment: @adeneo I think its pretty sure from my question that its not working i added demo

Comment: ok, not my bad.. not my plugin.. i just used that in many projects successfully..

Comment: @Hardy sry for the typo i am trying to create a one by myself

Comment: @Hardy can you please look into my first Demo identify what i am doing wrong

Comment: @adeneo Can you Please help ???  http://jsfiddle.net/Rz4dN/ this is the working one but its incosistent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that your code executes like this:

1. Bind first function to all elements where there is a currently class 'active1' and it will bind to all element that are available at the time bind() is called.
2. Bind second function to all elements where there is a currently class 'active2'  and it will bind to all element that are available at the time bind() is called.
3. The bind fires first function
4. Sets the class on the container to now be 'active2' (this element was not in the list obtained at step 2)

JQuery spec says:

**Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to bind()**

Do you not want to move the second bind inside the first function or just evoke the functionality there instead ?

```
function bindElement(elem, id) {

    $('.active1').on("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {

        alert("first");
        if (event.animationName === "three") {
            console.log('the event happened');
        }

        elem.removeClass('active active1');
        $(id).addClass('active');

        $(this).off("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend");
    });
}

function bindContainer(id) {

    $(id).addClass('active active2');
    $('.active2').on("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend", function (event) {

        alert("second");

        $(this).removeClass('active2');
        $(this).off("webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd msAnimationEnd animationend");
    });
}

$("a").click(function () {

    // Set the effect type
    var effect = 'slide';

    // Set the options for the effect type chosen
    var options = {
        direction: $('.mySelect').val()
    };

    // Set the duration (default: 400 milliseconds)
    var duration = 500;
    var $sel = $('div.active');
    var $class = $(this).attr('class');

    if ($class === 'Home') {

        $sel.addClass('active1');
        bindElement($sel, '#Container1');
        bindContainer('#Container1');
    }

    if ($class === 'Services') {

        $sel.addClass('active1');
        bindElement($sel, '#Container2');
        bindContainer('#Container2');
    }

    if ($class === 'About') {

        $sel.addClass('active1');
        bindElement($sel, '#Container3');
        bindContainer('#Container3');
    }

    if ($class === 'Contact') {

        $sel.addClass('active1');
        bindElement($sel, '#Container4');
        bindContainer('#Container4');
    }

});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5rLDD/)

Comment: Can you give a demo ??

Comment: Just add active1' to all required elements and 'active2' to all required containers (up front). Then call make the two bind calls which will find all the elements of each type. Then when one bind fires add or remove a class "animation-ending" on the appropioate element. In functions check for this attribute and if present do what you want and then remove this class and set the class on the container. SO in effect set binds on #container's and leave them. Use a flag class inside the function to determine if you execute code.

Comment: There where a number of issues with that: firstly you bound over and over again on every click - meaning multiple events fired. I forked a new fiddle with code that fires both events and does no multiple bind  http://jsfiddle.net/5rLDD/

Comment: why activex class was added

Comment: sorry - I was tyying something out - you can remove that

Comment: But it did helped to me get what i wanted no worries

Comment: +50 for a great answer

Answer (score 1):

Try using the JQuery transit plugin from:
http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

It uses CSS3 animations when available and works in almost every browser. Then you can just animate like:

```
$('div').transit({opacity: .5, rotateX: 30, delay: 200}, 2000, function(){

   // THE ANIMATION COMPLETED    

});
```

or you can chain those animations like:

```
$('div').transit({scale: 3.2}).transit({x: 300, y: 400}).transit({x:400, y: 500});
```

And please never post questions with half of the code in comments and all messy..

Comment: I need to translate in z axis direction which on checking this plugin does not have a provision for it

Comment: Then Can show the implementation of this in that plug in

Comment: I looked into it yeah but i want to know why this is happenning and want an answer without plugin that's why i put a bounty on the question

Comment: how to do the slide In effect .I did the slide in effect but how can do the slide out effect